# Azure Databricks Delta Table modifies the TIMESTAMP format while writing from Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am new to Azure Databricks,I am trying to write a dataframe output to a delta table which consists TIMESTAMP column. But strangely it changes the TIMESTAMP pattern after writing to delta table.
My DataFrame Output column holds the value in this format `2022-05-13 17:52:09.771`,
But After writing it to the Table, The column value is getting populated as

```
2022-05-13T17:52:09.771+0000
```

I am using below function to generate this Dataframe output

```
val pretsUTCText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
  val tsUTCText: String =  pretsUTCTextNew.format(ts)
  val tsUTCCol : Column = lit(tsUTCText)
  val df = df2.withColumn(to_timestamp(timestampConverter.tsUTCCol,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
```

The Dataframe output is returning `2022-05-13 17:52:09.771` as TIMESTAMP pattern.
But After writing it to Delta Table I see the same value is getting populated as `2022-05-13T17:52:09.771+0000`

Thanks in Advance. I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the same behaviour on Databricks as you, and it behaves differently than the Databricks [document](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_timestamp.html). It seems after some versions Databricks show timezone as a default so you see additional +0000.  I think you can use date_format function when you populate data if you don't want it. Also, I think you don't need 'Z' in format text as it is for timezone. See the screenshot below.

[image]